# How do I split up a large react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm learning react by programming the cardgame Solitaire. My main component, where I render the game board and the cards, has become very large (700 lines and growing).

The big bulk of that is all animation related and I would like to throw all the animation related methods into different files.

I'm not sure how to go about that in React. If I was doing this in Ruby, I would simply create a helper module, import the module and call the functions on the module. Creating a helper file and putting the functions in there doesn't seem to work in React, because I don't have access to "this" in those functions.

How would you deal with this situation in react? What patterns do people usually use when they want to separate out the logic in React components?

**Edit 1 (added example component):**

I've already read the React docs and I am already using Redux. My issue is that i have a lot of animations and UI moving around using JavaScript. Here's a link to the component I'm talking about:

https://gist.github.com/holgersindbaek/b8f134306148d12995dadf5e28d2d5b7

I'm keeping the current state of the game in the components "state". Once the Redux state changes, the props update and an animation is set off (move a card from old position "state" to new position "props". Once the animation is complete, the state of the component is updated so it's the same as the props.

My issue is that there's a lot of non-essential code in that component that's essentially just moving things around on the screen (initializeNewGame, initializeInteract, positionCardsOnBoard). How would you deal with such methods?

**Edit 2 (I think I figured it out):**

I've decided to place some of the animation functions in a helper file (animationHelper.js) and then import it in the React component and bind it to the component, so I can reference "this" in the animation function. I've updated the example to reflect the new changes:

https://gist.github.com/holgersindbaek/b8f134306148d12995dadf5e28d2d5b7

That seems like a good solution to me. Am I breaking any best practices by doing this?

Comment: Take 30 mins reading the react docs. Usually I would tell people to run away from any official docs, but they are really good.

Comment: You are on the right track of creating separate files. In react you create components in a hierarchy type structure where you can create sub components in different files, and import them into their parent files.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Thanks for the comment. I've already read the React docs and I'm already using Redux. I've been thinking about creating a parent component and keeping some of the big methods in that file, but it seems like a misuse of that pattern to me. Please see the updated question.

Comment: You can create child components that are able to interact with and change the parent component's state. Not sure if this is applicable for what you're doing though. Also you could probably move some of the animation functions into separate utility files for organization

Comment: @Jaked222 Moving the animation functions into a utility file seems like a good solution. I'm not sure how I can get access to "this" (the reference to the component itself) in the utility function though. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jaked222 I think I figured it out (see updated question above).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). Redux can help you keep your code scalable and maintainable. Basicaly, Redux allows you to split each component in two parts (or files), one for the view (components), and another for the busines logic (containers), which helps you test your code easely. Redux is a design pattern of unidirectional data flow.

In adition, you can apply some [S.O.L.I.D. principles](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design), applying Single Responsability for each component.

You can check an real example [here](https://github.com/darde/RD-Book-Store).

Comment: Redux is good for handling state data, but his problem is I don't even think he knows how to create child components to split up his code. He prob needs to learn that first.

Comment: Well, creating child components is a basic principle in React. Perhaps, @Holder can put some code here, this way we can show him how to create child components based on his code.

Comment: I agree with the redux portion though, as the state management would be uncontrollable very quickly creating a game.

Comment: @PabloDarde Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already using Redux. The reason my file is so big, is that I have a lot of animations I'm running on the components elements. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @PabloDarde I think I found a solution. See the updated question above.

Comment: Hi @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk, great! I feel happy you got a good solution :)